# undefined columns when trying to use separate function

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a code that I built to scrape player data from yahoo's fantasy football player page so I can get a list of players and the rank that yahoo gives them.

The code worked fine last year but now I am getting an error when I run the separate function:

```
> temp <- separate(temp,two,c('Note', 'Player','a','b','c','Opp'), sep="\n", remove=TRUE)
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, x_vars) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
Expected 6 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [1].
```

I cannot figure out why it is giving this error, the column I am trying to separate looks correct. I have another script that uses this function to do something similar and when I went to try to use it there it worked fine.
The "missing pieces filled in with 'NA'" warning shouldn't be a problem, just that it wont run because of the undefined columns error.

The minimal code that I use to get to where I am is this:

```
library(rvest)## For read.html
library(tidyr)## For separate function

#scrapes the data
url <- 'https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/107573/players?status=A&pos=O&cut_type=9&stat1=S_S_2017&myteam=0&sort=PR&sdir=1&count=0'
web <- read_html(url) 
table = html_nodes(web, 'table')
temp <- html_table(table)[[2]]
#

colnames(temp) <- c('one','two',3:26)

temp <- separate(temp,two,c('Note', 'Player','a','b','c','Opp'), sep="\n", remove=TRUE)
```

The data is scraped in without names so I quickly give names to them including spelling out the column in question so it works with the separate function. I have tried using quotation marks around two in separate but it give the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After remove the first row of `temp`, you code works.

```
library(dplyr)

colnames(temp) <- c('one','two',3:ncol(temp)) 
# Use ncol(temp) to make sure the column number is correct 

temp2 <- temp %>%
  filter(row_number() > 1) %>%
  separate(two, c('Note', 'Player','a','b','c','Opp'), sep="\n", remove=TRUE)
```